# lightbox2 unsafe data image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, lightbox2

I am trying to use lightbox2 with a data URL which is dymacilly set by Angularjs but for some reason it's not showing the image. In my console I get an error showing the data URL I set dynamically with ng-href but "unsafe" is prefixed to the url.

Anybody has a clue why this happens? I already added "data" to the white list of Angular and I also see that in the DOM the href is correct.

```
config(['$compileProvider',
        function ($compileProvider) {
            $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data):/);
        }]);
```

There is no "unsafe" prefixed only when I click on the link I get this error.

The error that I get in the console looks like this:

```
unsafe:data:image/png;base64,net:{the base 64 string}:ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

My link looks like this:

```
<a ng-href="data:image/png;base64,{{schedule.flyer}}" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption" >
```

If I add the base64 string directly in a normal href it works fine. Does anybody know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should use the `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` method per https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider

Comment: Yes that was the issue indeed. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I configured the wrong white list. I should have used the following code:

```
config(['$compileProvider',
        function ($compileProvider) {
            $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|local|data):/);
        }]);
```